# Why Do I Need Permission To Convert Files In FFMPEG?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Using java, why this code doesn't work?

```
File fileToConvert = new File("/Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/media/ios/prova.wav");

        File fileConverted = new File("/Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/media/ios/prova.mp3");

        File ffmpeg = new File("/Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/programs/ffmpeg");

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg + " -i " + fileToConvert + " " + fileConverted);
```

I'm using mac OS. This is the complete stacktracke:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/programs/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:415)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:312)
    at com.edosocial.EdosocialApplication.main(EdosocialApplication.java:55)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
    ... 10 more
```

ALl help is welcome.

Comment: In a terminal window, do `ls -l /Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/programs/ffmpeg`.  The first part of the output line should start with the four characters `-rwx`.  If it doesn’t contain an `x` then that file is not executable.  You can set executable permission with a command like `chmod +x /Users/e/java/projects/edosocial/src/main/resources/static/programs/ffmpeg`.

Comment: Hi. I have checked and there was no x, so it's not executable. I've tries to set it executable the way you said but it doesn't work; when I check the output is the same as before.

Comment: Do the `ls -l` command again.  What permissions do you see?

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm trying a thing

Comment: @VGR I finally found out the solution. Coming from a PHP background, I would have like a folder containing ffmpeg and it would work fine. With java I need an EXECUTABLE program, which in Mac OS has the black icon with written "exec" in green. So I just needed to use that. I really thank you for giving the solution. Have a nice life.